# How to reduce the size of list item in android?

Tags: android

I have gone through the link http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/01/android/android-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/ and executed the **listview sample** in android. **I found the link very useful.**

But I want to reduce the size of the list item...i.e.: each **listitem height became very big so i kept my images size from 60*60 to 32*32. But even then the same problem. How to reduce the height of listitem?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ListView.setLayoutParams(width,height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use getWidth() and getHeight() method of listview in onWindowFocusChanged to get widtha nd height of list view

```
 @Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);


    System.out.println("width of list view..."+listview.getWidth());
    System.out.println("height of list view111..."+listview.getHeight());

}
```